# Ubuntu One Tomboy sync fails with "The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND."

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy, notes

I'm trying to set up Tomboy notes sync with Ubuntu One. I've followed the instructions in [this guide](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-notes-sync/). I get this successful authorization screen:

[image: tomboy auth screen]

And this is what my sync preferences screen looks like:

[image: tomboy sync settings]

When I click "Save" in the sync preferences I get this success screen:

[image: ready to sync]

But when I click "Yes" I get this failure screen:

[image: fail screen]

I think this is the relevant error from my .xsession-errors file:

```
[ERROR 09:38:25.560] Caught exception. Message: The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND.
[ERROR 09:38:25.561] Stack trace for previous exception:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR 09:38:25.561] Rest of stack trace for above exception:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.MakeWebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parameters, System.String postData)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.WebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.String postData)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.Get(System.String uri, IDictionary`2 queryParameters)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetUser(System.String userUri, IWebConnection connection)
   at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.BeginSyncTransaction()
   at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartUnsafe()
[ERROR 09:38:25.561] Synchronization failed with the following exception: The remote server returned an error: (404) NOT FOUND.
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

And the full output of `tomboy --debug` is [here](http://pastebin.com/mcUbBQcH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who have this problem, this turned out to be a problem with my account that Ubuntu One support had to fix.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the step 'Return to Tomboy Preferences and click Save'
When you return to the preferences window 'Save' is greyed out.
What you need to do is edit the 'Server' field to get the Save button to be clickable.
So https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/ delete the last trailing slash '/' so it reads
https://one.ubuntu.com/notes
Then the Save button will be clickable.

The bug for this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/845321

Comment: That bug is fixed in Tomboy 1.8.0-1ubuntu1.1 and I'm able to click 'Save' after the authorization screen. It's after that when I try to sync that I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I use Tomboy extensively and have noticed my 200+ notes no longer syncing properly. This has been going on now for a couple of weeks. Is there a Tomboy note limit? Is there something wrong with the server? With the new changes with Ubuntu One?

On 1st system when I create a note, all is fine. On 2nd system that tries to sync the notes, Tomboy ALWAYS crashes and whatever notes I had synced on the 1st computer are now deleted. And it crashes and deletes vice versa as well.

Its very frustrating as this is one of my fave apps. Any tips or advice?